# Pull data from an interactive map on a website

Tags: javascript, database, web-scraping

I want to get data on the number of Covid cases in LA County by Zip code (or the finest geographical unit the data could be).

On the website of the LA's Public Health Department (http://dashboard.publichealth.lacounty.gov/covid19_surveillance_dashboard/), there is a map displaying the number of cases by city/community. I want to somehow pull and download this data as well as the geometry of the city/community to make the maps myself. However, I don't know how to do this.

On the dropdown menu on the left there is a table data for the number of cases but I cannot get the geometry from these.

I have no experience with Javascript so I would appreciate any help or if anyone could point me to where to obtain similar data that would be really helpful too!